# loading dependent of a dependent JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have a code that will run on browsers and I'm writing test cases for it in mocha. 
But I'm facing a problem:

parent.js

```
function EntityAbstract() {    
    this.$Ver = '';
}
EntityAbstract.method('setVer', function($Ver) {
        this.$Ver = $Ver;
});
```

child.js

```
function Note($Id, $Text) {
    this.$Id = $Id;
    this.$Text = $Text;
}

Note.inherits(EntityAbstract);
```

The above code works fine when I include it in the html file using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/scripts/Structure/parent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/scripts/Structure/child.js"></script>
```

Now, while I am trying to write test cases for child.js using mocha in node.js environment.

```
require('node-import');
var entity = imports('src/app/scripts/Structure/parent');
var note = imports('src/app/scripts/Structure/child');
```

It throws an error:

```
ReferenceError: EntityAbstract is not defined at Node.inherits(EntityAbstract)
```

Note: I cannot do changes in child.js which won't be supported by the browser.

Comment: What library are you using here? the _method_ and _inherits_ methods are not native JavaScript

Comment: I have added these in function.prototype. You can see here for better understanding. http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html